# Restoring my previous "Current State" in VirtualBox after restoring my snapshop

Tags: virtualbox, backup, restore, visual-studio-code, parrot-os

I made a terrible mistake, I was working on sync **VScode** onto my ParrotOS **Virtualbox**. I thought I copied files from my Virtualbox to my shared file. When I restored the snapshot and restored the previous image, I moved the folder that I was working on into the same location and open it. But I found that I didn't move the full files from this folder.

Now, I want to restore my previous **Current State** and I don't know-how. I searched for it a lot But I didn't find a solution.

- Can someone help me if I can restore the files from the previous **current State** or even from **VSCode**?
  [image]

Comment: A snapshot is a file of changes, not a backup. It is meant to be combined or discarded. If you have combined it (I think you did combine it) there is no way I know to uncombine it. I will look around but I do not think so.

Comment: @John I will really appreciate your help. can I restore the previous image of Virtualbox using **Hetman Partition Recovery**?

Comment: I spent some time looking the snapshot usage and requirements for use. I think once combined you have no way back.

Comment: can I even use an external program to get it back? I still have `Parrot Security.vbox-prev`  file but its too small. does it even help ?

Comment: I have not seen a third party program for this. At  least in part snapshots are very tightly integrated with the virtual app involved.

Comment: can you check link, please >> https://superuser.com/questions/771086/how-to-recover-previous-current-state-from-virtualbox-after-restoring-from-s

Comment: The accepted answer in that case was overall the same as my post above. It does say you might recover pieces of the prior  (before snapshot) image, but that was for one case plus a suggestion of trying a file recovery program.  That is about all you can do.